# How do I convince someone else to DM?

Tags: dnd-5e

I convinced a group of friends to start playing Dungeons & Dragons a while ago and I have run an adventure or two.  Sadly, I have never been able to play as a PC because nobody else is willing to be the DM: they always say that it is too hard or there are too many rules....

I have tried asking them if they want me to teach them, but still they do not want to.

Is there any way to convince them to run a game? It's kinda sucking the fun out of the game for me.

Comment: Welcome to rpg.se! What have you tried so far to solve your problem? Also, I think [this question](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/58829/4398)  is closely related to yours and may be helpful.

Comment: Well so far i have asked if they would like me to teach them how to play and if they would like to try being the DM, i would be more than willing to teach them but they are just not willing to even try.

Comment: Excellent! The more information like that which you can [edit] into your question, the better. Details about your situation help answerers ensure their solutions will actually help with the problem you face.