# Getting Players to Share GM Duty?

Tags: multiple-gm

Has anybody here had any success getting players to take turns GMing sessions. I've tried a couple of times and had no takers. I offered incentives most recently, in the form of guaranteed extra XP and other rewards, but again, no takers. Any thoughts?

Comment: Sure, I've done it before. Each player takes turns GMing each session. Sounds like your players don't want for whatever reason. What exactly is the question?

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to get buy-in from my players. I stated up front that I expected people to take turns running, but all I got was one person saying they wanted to run a completely different game on alternate weeks; I'm currently planning to play that one having shut down mine.

Comment: You stated up front your expectations, and they joined the game. Clearly they are at least a bit ok with it. Do you know why they don't seem willing? Perhaps they are not experienced at being the DM so it's daunting? Maybe they don't have ideas for what to run?

Comment: Unfortunately, I think this is a duplicate of [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/87607/how-do-i-convince-someone-else-to-dm), which is closed as Primarily Opinion-based (and I can't actually duplicate it.)

Comment: [My answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/58845/4398) to "How do I convince my group to try a new system without always having to DM it first?" may be useful, also. And when you get 20+ rep, feel free to join us in the [chat] for more free-form discussions than the site's strict Q&A format allows.