# Stats for homunculus created by Alchemist with Promethean Disciple discovery - how to get it buffed up, RAW?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, alchemist, constructs

One of my ex players ([ex as we're switching DM currently](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/142499/10642), she is still active) wanted to create a homunculus. She took [Promethean Disciple](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist/discoveries/paizo-alchemist-discoveries/promethean-disciple) because, for some reasons, [Promethean Alchemist](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist/archetypes/paizo-alchemist-archetypes/promethean-alchemist-alchemist-archetype/) did not appeal to her.

Now she is level 8, and time, money, access to spells, blood and body parts are not of any particular concern to her at this point in the campaign. And man, what a collection of preserved body part she has! Prehensile tongues, wings etc.

The goal is to have [homunculus](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/constructs/homunculus/) (or homunculus-themed [flesh golem](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/constructs/golem/golem-flesh/)) that is small or medium, has wings and boggart (frog-humanoid) tongue, and probably can "cast" one or two alchemical effects 1/day, too.

In my game it would not be a problem at all, given all the time and effort she put into it in game*, but because we're transiting between DMs, I wanted to ask you, how close can we get to do this, RAW?

---

* Like, most of her character doings was experiments with flesh alchemy in order to build herself a servant she envied Promethean Alchemists. Actual 3/4 of her roleplay, honestly!

Answer (score 4):

### There are rules that allow adding/improving a Fly speed and Spell-Like Abilities

The rules for Construct crafting include rules for [modification](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/item-creation-feats/craft-Construct-item-creation/#Modifying_Constructs).

Homunculi begin with a Fly speed, but it can be improved for "having wings":

> Constructs with a fly speed can improve these speeds by 10 feet, up to a total speed equal to double the original speed, at a cost of 4,000 gp per 10-foot improvement.

And [Homunculi](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/constructs/homunculus/) in partucular can gain 1/day Spell-Like Abilities:

> Spell-Like Ability: By incorporating 10 potions of the same spell in the homunculus’s creation, a crafter can imbue the homunculus with the power to use that spell once per day as a spell-like ability. Price: Total cost of the potions used.

Unfortunately, no Construct rules allow for gaining a prehensile appendage, such as a tongue.

### Your (former) player probably wants [Fleshwarper](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/item-creation-feats/fleshwarper-item-creation/).

There is no example Fleshgraft for a prehensile tongue, but it does provide the structure for accomplishing it and gives the player the mechanical means to do so. They will have to work out with the new GM an appropriate statblock. Bonus: it's based on Craft (Alchemy) and seems to cannonize what the player was already doing.

Notes:

- They can consider [Wings of Darkness](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/item-creation-feats/fleshwarper-item-creation/#Wings_of_Darkness) if they prefer this method.
- [Grasping Tendril](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/item-creation-feats/fleshwarper-item-creation/#Grasping_Tendril) is probably the best starting place for the tongue.